# Mac apache2 local host and reinstalling

Tags: macos, apache

after all kinds of editing :( :/ yea....

1: localhost will open it works! and when you refresh the page it does not work and refresh the page again and it shows up again.

2: even after running sudo apachectl stop localhost still shows it works

3: running in terminal jobs shows 9 sudo vi /etc/apache/httpd.conf

4: at one time https.config had php7 now only shows php5 after some other edits

?????any way to complete just remove apache and reinstall the hole apache?????

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of editing files around found out the solution was:
for

#3 on unix ie Mac
   1....( run the command in terminal) rm .httpd.conf.swp 
   2.... (then going back in and editing files as follows run ..... )
    nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
   3.... (change the text of ((LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so))                just change the 5 to a 7  then hit control o then  enter then control x 
   4.... run.  apachectl restart and  open web browser run localhost

now if you want php add the phpmyadmin folder downloaded from phpmyadmin
first  rename the folder to phpmyadmin after it has been unzipped and move it into the folder located at your Mac harddrive/Library/webserver/document you should also see your index.html.en

by the way editing this index.html.en file will let you know when you run localhost if this is intact the location it is rendering.   another problem some have if they use other things like node.js mongodb and so forth and or files moved around.